# How to display macro definition in vim

Tags: vim, plugins

How can I make the vim `[d` command to display the C/C++ macro definition using the tags file?

Or is there a plugin can display the C/C++ macro definition provided by the tags file in menu style or in the command bar?

Comment: By default, `[d` looks for macros based on the `'define'`, `'include'`, and `'path'` options.  You want to get similar behavior, but use the tags file instead?  I am not sure what you mean by "menu style" nor "command bar".  For consistency, I try to use terms the same way they are used in the vim help files.

Answer (score 1):

If your macro definition appears on the tags file you should be able to jump to the macro definition with `:tag` or Ctrl-].

The tags file is a regular text file, so you can check if the tag is present using a regular search command.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the Tagbar plugin does what you want:  http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3465 or https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar .  This is a replacement for the older Taglist plugin.

Comment: This plugin seems better than the taglist, thanks. But I am looking for a convenient method to display the macro definition.